# My in-app product was charged, however it is not seen in revenue section of Google Play Console. Why?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

My in-app product was charged, however it is not seen in revenue section of Google Play Console. Or it will be seen after some times. Here is the screenshots:
[image: charged screenshot link]
[image: no revenue screenshot link]

Comment: is it in a none released state?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs
 yes, yesterday I unpublished it for some times

Comment: In my tests, I realized that in app billing, analytics and achievements only work if it is in alpha, beta test or released and installed as an released apk (not via Android Studio). So I guess if you unpublished it, everything is disabled automatically.